# MS Access VBA Code Evaluation Error when sharing ACCDE file on a Network

Tags: ms-access, vba

I currently have an MS Access 2016 Application that I am running on a shared network.  The front end is an ACCDE file saved in a shared folder with the backend saved in a subfolder of that same folder (anyone with access to the front end has access to the back end).  I am having users create a shortcut on their desktop to access the Front End.  This allows me to make minor updates without requiring everyone to download the newest version.  Most features of the tool work fine.  However I keep running into an issue on one of the forms.  I have a Before Update event, when you navigate away from the record, the system will ask you if you would like to save.  If you click yes, the following error message comes up:

"The expression Before Update you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: the Save Action was cancelled.
This error occurs when an event has failed to run because the location of the logic for the event cannot be evaluated. For example, if the OnOpen property of a form is set to =[Field], this error occurs because a macro or event name is expected to run when the event occurs."

This is the VBA code that I am attempting to run.  Would really appreciate it if anyone can help me here.  Thank you!

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If BooReSequence = True Then
Exit Sub
End If
'When exit current tab with unsaved changes, pop up option for 'Discard' or 'Save'
Dim TLResponse As Integer

If Forms.frmFullCourseInfo.sbfrmTrainingElements.Form.Dirty Then
TLResponse = MsgBox("Do you want to save your changes?", vbYesNo, "Unsaved Changes")

  If TLResponse = vbYes Then
      DoCmd.Save
  Else
      Me.Undo
  End If

End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

> The front end is an ACCDE file saved in a shared folder with the backend saved in a subfolder of that same folder (anyone with access to the front end has access to the back end). I am having users create a shortcut on their desktop to access the Front End. This allows me to make minor updates without requiring everyone to download the newest version.

That can also lead to precisely the kind of problems you describe. Everyone **must** have their own local copy of the front-end file.

Comment: I actually just figured out what the problem was.  The link below explains the issue, basically the DoCmd.save command was necessary.  I removed it and the problem was solved.  Other than this, I haven't ran into issues with sharing the file across the network and users accessing via a shortcut.  Gord, what types of issues will I run into?  I have only deployed to a small number of users thus far (<10).  

Thank you!

https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/898906-docmd-save-problem-multiple-users

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree with Gord. There is no evidence to suggest his statement is correct. I build numerous front end (FE) and back end (BE) Access applications, with heavy form driven interaction and almost entirely done in VBA. I have upwards to 60 people using a single file at one time and never run into this kind of problem. It all comes down to how well you build the [BE]. The more you do via VBA and the less you utilize front end controls like bound forms, the more power you wield behind the scenes.

Comment: In my case I have a completely benign BE structure yet I must have separate FE databases, else I experience database locking problems among other difficult-to-trace bugs.  Opposite of Craigs advice, I only had problems when VBA executed behind my forms. Basic forms with standard bound controls behaved normally, but multiple users accessing the same database file and form with VBA, it failed. Perhaps Gord's use of "must" was a bit strong for Craig, but separate copies of the FE can solve the problem in some cases. Local copies of the FE also improve performance by reducing network traffic.